# line integral finding parametric equation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, line-integrals

Compute $\int \limits_{C} F.dr$ for $F(x,y)=(x-y,x+y)$ and $C$ is the curve given by $x^2+y^2=x+y$ while going clockwise.

So this is a circle which is $$(x-\frac12)^2+(y-\frac12)^2=(\frac1{\sqrt2})^2$$

To parameterise it, I was thinking we can let $ x = \frac12 + \frac1{\sqrt2}\cos(\theta) $ and $y = \frac12 + \frac1{\sqrt2}\sin(\theta) $ so we can have $r(\theta)=(\ \frac12 + \frac1{\sqrt2}\cos(\theta), \frac12 + \frac1{\sqrt2}\sin(\theta) $ but what are the limits?

Comment: The limits are $0$ and $2\pi$ or more generally any two real numbers $a,b$ such that $a<b$ and $b-a=2k\pi$, for some $k\in \mathbb N$. Here it's safe to assume that the desired value of $k$ is $1$.

Comment: wouldn't that mean that it is anticlockwise?

Comment: You're right, my bad. What you need to adjust is the expression. What does $\theta\mapsto (\sin(\theta),\cos(\theta))$ do?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that arrow. also I thought it would just be $0$ to $-2\pi$?

Comment: I meant for you to consider a parametrization $\vec r$ (of a different set) given by $\vec r(\theta)=(\sin(\theta),\cos(\theta))$. What you say probably works, I'd need to check. But it raises an issue which I'm don't know whether you're supposed to ignore or not and the issue is the domain of $r$ which obviously can't be $[-2\pi, 0]$.

Comment: I see, but your r would just be for when the circle is in the origin with radius 1 wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, it would. You need to tweak it to fit your problem.

Comment: But how? I don't get it...

Comment: I meant to say that the domain can't be $[0,-2\pi]$ (which is the empty set). It's a typo in my comment above.

Comment: wait I didn't mean what the domain of t is when I said how to find the limits. I meant the limits of t when integrating because surely you can have limits from b to a where b>a.

Comment: I know, that's why I said what I said on my comment above. To integrate you need a parametrization, the domain is implied. But sometimes all this stuff is ignored depending on how the material is being taught, and the focus is on the geometry of it. That's why I said it probably works, but there's an issue.

Comment: Please can you show me your way of doing this which causes no problems.